# Retrieving private youtube playlists with javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Does anyone know a good method for retrieving another user's private playlist via the youtube api using javascript?  I'm assuming there has to be some authentication needed to do this, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with where to start.  My searches haven't returned much information on this.  Would I need to use something like OAuth?  Thanks!

Comment: What are the characteristics of the private playlist of another user?
To access a private playlist of another user, which contains private videos, I think that the other user must share with you the private videos first  and then the playlist

Comment: the experimental Youtube API v3 is able to do this; you have a user authenticate with your app via oAuth2 and authorize your app, then you can issue calls to retrieve the private playlists.